# Spring Data REST - Exclude Subtypes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-rest

Lets say I have the following Hibernate Entities (fields ommitted)

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "T")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class SuperClass {
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(name = "subClassA")
public SubClassA extends SuperClass {
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(name = "subClassB")
public SubClassB extends SuperClass {
}
```

With Spring Data REST I would get the following JSON representation:

```
{
  "_links": {
  },
  "_embedded": {
    "subclassA": [
      {
        "field1": "",
        "field2": ""
      }
    ],
    "subclassB": [
      {
        "field1": "",
        "field2": "",
        "field3": ""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Again ommiting the _links attributes. Is there some sort of configuration I can use so the Serializer can ignore the subclasses and do a representation like this:

```
{
  "_links": {
  },
  "_embedded": {
    "superClass": [
      {
        "field1": "",
        "field2": ""
      },
      {
        "field1": "",
        "field2": "",
        "field3": ""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Good question but we are ok `field3` is a member of `SuperClass`? Else it can be strange

Comment: Moreover you can find an opened issue about the subject on SDR Jira: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-344

Comment: field3 is only a member of subclassB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve the problem would be the implementation of a `RelProvider`. All you need to do is to implement it and add it to spring container (this could be done but i.e. annotating the implementation with @Component).

Considering that you would be able to get the response you are expecting simply by adding the following implementation (considering it will be scanned by spring):

```
@Component
public class MessageRelProvider implements RelProvider {

    public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
        return SuperClass.class.isAssignableFrom(arg0);
    }

    public String getItemResourceRelFor(Class<?> type) {
        return "superClass";
    }

    public String getCollectionResourceRelFor(Class<?> type) {
        return "superClasses";
    }

}
```